# Keeping AppModule as a Singleton

Tags: java, guice

In my application (standalone), when I need to get some object instance from `Guice`, I usually do it like this:

```
injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());
instance = injector.getInstance(MyInterface1.class);
```

I was wondering:

- Why do I need to pass an *instance* of the `AppModule` class, and not the module class reference itself, so Guice could instantiate it?
- What side-effects should I expect if I keep my `AppModule` class as a **singleton**, therefore always using the same instance when calling `Guice.createInjector()`?

As a side note:

- What about the Injector itself? How bad design would it be if I keep just one instance of it somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Passing an instance to `createInjector` allows you to configure the module to your liking via constructor parameters. Guice does not mutate the `Module`s so you could keep them around, but a better practice is what you're already doing: create a single `Injector` and bootstrap your application from there. As your application grows you'll write more modules and you don't want to manage that complexity yourself.

You shouldn't have to maintain a reference to the `Injector` because you can always just inject it, although there are a limited number of cases where this is appropriate. It makes more sense to inject the actual dependencies into your class. This makes the dependency hierarchy clear and your code much more testable.

Comment: Well, I'm working on a Standalone application, so I can't just expect to `@Inject` the Injector. Actually, If I could `@Inject` my dependencies, I wouldn't even be using this approach.

Comment: Why can't you @Inject your dependencies?